# Fix different format of data by regexp_replace statement

Tags: sql, format, case-when, regexp-replace

I am trying to make a taxonomy format in the database consistent. One format is divided by colon, and another format is divided by slash. For example: 
1) Meat: Pork: Ground Pork 
2) Meat/Pork/Ground Pork

I tried to use case when and regexp_replace statement:

```
Select 
case when locate('/',taxonomy)> 0 
    then regexp_replace(taxonomy, '/', ':') 
else case when locate ('/', taxonomy)=0 
    then regexp_replace(taxonomy,':',':') end as taxonomy from sales.directory
```

However, I am getting NULL for the fields that was originally divided by colon. I think I probably set the part after else incorrectly. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `else` there.

Comment: Don't you want to update the column to fix the data for good, not just when you select it? P.S. Check your select case syntax.